# What is the purpose of the "token" custom display setting?

Tags: 8, tokens

On the `manage display` page of a given content type, you can choose between various display settings. The most commons are "teaser" and "default" or "full content".

However, there's also a "token" display mode (disabled by default). I assume it's added by the [token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) contrib module, but I have no idea what its purpose is and how we're supposed to take advantage of it?

Also: is it typically used somewhere that I'm not aware of? Can it be safely deleted if it's not activated?

Comment: I believe (though may be terribly wrong) that is for altering the tokens. So if I would use `[node:field_image]` it would normally display the image with the content type default image style (large), however you can force another image style for the token.

Comment: Oooh, yes, that would make sense AND it would be very interesting! I'll test that, since I need to use tokens to set meta tags on a new site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Neograph734 commented, it allows you to change the output of field tokens without actually changing the default display of the field. You can find more information here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1299662

Actually, a similar question already has been answered: [Effective use of tokens view mode?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34245/effective-use-of-tokens-view-mode)